# How do you compile CoffeeScript in a Jakefile?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, jake

I would like to create a Jakefile which compiles some CoffeeScripts to install a NodeJS application.

How do you do that?

I tried with:
https://gist.github.com/1241827

but it's a weak approach, definitely not classy.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approx snippet I have used:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var coffee = require('coffee-script')

// If you'd like to see compiled code..
// console.log(coffee.compile(fs.readFileSync('coffee.coffee')))

// ..otherwise
fs.writeFileSync('output.js', coffee.compile(fs.readFileSync('input.coffee')))
```

..assumes you have the `coffee-script` node module installed, of course.

Translated from this [Cakefile](https://github.com/Plexical/underscore.geospatial/blob/master/Cakefile) of mine.

Comment: I already had a look at the .compile() method of coffee, but I was wondering if there was a way not to use the FS.

Anyway, thanks, I will use this snippet!